# Related questions section mostly irrelevant

Tags: discussion, related-questions

The related questions section doesn't seem to have a good algorithm to pick recently asked or updated questions. I mostly see questions from 2 or 3 years ago with no recent activity. Most of the time the question is not valid anymore as situation has changed or improved, or answer is invalid at this point.Can the suggestion in related questions be improved or is there a good reason why old questions be suggested?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20473/how-are-related-questions-selected

Comment: On the main site I would agree that the section is mostly irrelevant; maybe not for the reasons given here, but google is still the better way to find relevant questions. The site's features just don't compete, be it the search or the related questions bar. On meta however it is quite often very useful.

Comment: A question being old or without recent activity does not make it less related. Some old posts still provide the best solution to date, and, if they don't, they should be updated, not hidden away. [se] is, at least in part, intended to be an archive of useful information, not something where only what happened in the last few days matters. But related questions are indeed not that useful.

Comment: Old questions *are* relevant. In fact, your new question should show that the knowledge on those questions has been used or at least attempted.