# For the purposes of the "Related" section of the Q&A UI, what definition of "related" aligns closely to what users of Stack Overflow find value in?

Tags: discussion, related-questions, content-discovery

At the time of this writing, SE Inc. is experimenting with Machine-Learning-powered links in the "Related" section of the Q&A UI. There's a question that I see as a *prerequisite* to having fruitful discussion on this that I'm not sure if we've ever "sat down and talked about":

What definition of "related" is useful to users of of Stack Overflow for the purpose of displaying in that section of the UI?

The word "related" on its own is quite nebulous.

It's a pretty uncontroversial position that the "Related" section of the UI is not very useful (see [Review / remove the related question section](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385267/11107541), [Related question list is REALLY irrelevant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423775/11107541), [Unrelated "related questions" keep appearing because of high vote count](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266605/11107541), [Related questions section mostly irrelevant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358126/11107541)). (Okay to be fair, there's also [a pretty highly upvoted post from 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268046/11107541) that praises the Related Questions listing as actually being very useful, but I don't think that hold true today).

Part of me wonders if this is (in a long chain of cause-and-effect) a result of not having "sat down and talked about it" (about what "related" means / should mean) (how do you design a solution without first clearly describing the problem it should solve?). If we've already sat down and talked about this before, my apologies. I looked briefly through all the questions here tagged [related-questions](/questions/tagged/related-questions) and didn't see such discussion. I also don't such see a "formal definition" in the current [tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/related-questions/info).

I tried thinking of some possible meanings:

- "I bet you were or will later wonder X given that you are wondering Y"
- "I bet you'll find question X fun and interesting"
- "X might have already been asked here"
- "these questions have some same words, similar tags, and are scored very highly"

Which do you think aligns closely to what people would find valuable to see in this specific section of the UI when they visit Stack Overflow? <sup><sub>(something might be valuable, but not necessarily be the most appropriate fit for this specific section of the UI)</sub></sup>

(If you think I've missed a possible meaning (I wouldn't be surprised), please say so (ideally in an answer post discussing it))

And as always, with questions like this, let's do ["good subjective"](/help/dont-ask): If you want to speak for yourself, please speak from *experiences* rather than opinions (Ex. "I come to Stack Overflow for X purpose, so Y would be useful to me" instead of "nobody comes to Stack Overflow to do X"), and if possible and relevant, give citations and references.

Comment: Regarding "these questions have some same words, similar tags, and are scored very highly", that might not be very useful for users to actually click on, but it might be useful for SEO purposes to make sure that questions with higher score are more likely to show up in search engines. I'm not entirely sure how Stack Overflow does their SEO, but I wouldn't be surprised if that's part of it.

Comment: @DonaldDuck ok. so are you suggesting that you think having that section of the UI be used for optimizing a given Q&A page's SEO is valuable to the majority of SO's users? Because I'm not convinced of that on first thought (but maybe you can convince me if that's indeed what you think). And it seems like a rather roundabout way to increase page ranking of high-scoring posts (though I don't know much about optimizing page ranking).

Comment: "I bet you'll find question X fun and interesting" or "X might have already been asked here" are not related (to Y) at all, or where would the possible relation be? I guess that most people recognize related questions when they see them. Usually they have the same or a similar topic.

Comment: @Trilarion I think "X might have already been asked here" is (if accurate), very related to "Y" (the question that links _to_ the "related" question)

Answer (score 7):

I'll speak from personal experience here.

For this specific section of the UI, "I bet you were or will later wonder X given that you are wondering Y" would be useful to me given what I come to Stack Overflow for.

Except when I'm looking for things to answer, I come here with a specific problem, and want to find a solution to that problem. That's pretty much it. Have problem, search, find, I'm in, I'm out. (repeat when I encounter a new problem). I don't stick around looking for random things that look interesting, and I don't go on clicking sprees to explore things.

A significant portion of the users of Stack Overflow are "read-only" (they have never felt a need to make contributions, and hence don't have accounts), which is why I've put my point of view in their same shoes first (even though these days I mostly just look for things to answer).

What would be useful to me, is if that section of the UI could somehow predict what question I might have next based on the question I'm looking at.

---

For the other suggested definitions of "related", here are my thoughts:

- "*I bet you'll find question X fun and interesting*": I have personally never used Stack Overflow for such exploratory purposes. But I feel like this is the outcome of the current Elasticsearch implementation of the "Related" section. I personally resonate with what many users have expressed on meta: this is not that useful to me, given what I come to Stack Overflow for (problems I have, and their solutions). I'm not saying this is not something worth exploring, but I don't think it should be given that space in the UI.
- "*X might have already been asked here*": The right place for it is the place (and time) we are already putting it: In the Ask-Question UI. Though it would also be useful to have a dedicated UI section for other users (Ex. close-voters and answerers).
- "*these questions have some same words, similar tags, and are scored very highly*": This is useful to me when I'm searching for things using the search bar. But it's not something I've ever though to myself of wanting to see in the section of the UI in question. This is what (in my observation) we have currently.

Comment: Regarding *""X might have already been asked here"* not being a good fit for this section: I disagree.  Most of the people being shown this are not the asker, and should in fact be directed to posts that might answer the question, either in case they have the same question and are researching it, or so that they can flag it as a duplicate.  Additionally, it's well-established that people don't read things that are shown to them in the ask-question flow, so offering them again (to both the asker and others who might point the asker to them) is indeed useful.

Comment: @RyanM I agree that duplicate suggestions for _answerers_ would also be useful. I think that can also be its own UI section. I know that that's been proposed before. Let me go find the links. In the meantime, I've edited to clarify my position.

Comment: I think "A significant portion" is quite an understatement for over 90% of traffic https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123390/216313

Answer (score 2):

Thank you again for your time and attention to this. When we started this initiative, our goal was to improve discoverability for our users and make it easier to find relevant information to address their needs. This can mean a lot of different things (i.e. improve search) but we focused our efforts on question pages because 1) that’s where most of the traffic is today and 2) users come to us for specific needs (i.e. solutions to their problems).

Before we kicked off experimentation, we conducted a literature review on MSO/MSE to learn more about what has been shared about the “Related” section. We agree we also did not see anywhere the community had “sat down and talked about” what “related” should be. But we did find a few posts asking about the [logic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20473/how-are-related-questions-selected), [ordering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311611/how-are-related-questions-ordered), [visibility](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65495/linked-related-questions-visibility) and [how often they’re updated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176001/related-questions-is-not-updated).  So that is where we started exploring.

One of the meanings you listed, “X might have already been asked here”, is also one of the reasons why we’ve started to dig deeper into what hasn’t been touched in over a decade. We asked, “ If the current question page a user landed on from a Google search results page doesn’t solve their problems, what if seeing related questions can guide them a step closer in the right direction?” These are the problems we hope to solve with this feature.

However what we are learning during this initiative also includes other amazing use cases of how this feature could be of benefit. We learned that curators, users who contribute to the platform through maintaining and cultivating objective content, could use “Related” to help identify duplicate questions to be flagged. This was an interesting use case that we hadn’t considered given that the majority of users who visit us are anonymous.

Improving relevance and making it easier for users to find helpful information are complex problems to address which is why we’ve decided to try machine learning. It’s also difficult to measure relevance as we think it’s somewhat subjective (what someone finds useful might not always be the case for someone else). We’re collecting a lot of data through experimentation to determine what signals could be correlated to demonstrating users finding value.

This is why we were so excited to see your questions being posed to the community. Having this kind of understanding of what users are looking for is invaluable to us to better define our goal. We want to incorporate as much as we can and consider the community's feedback for these improvements, so thank you again for working with us on this.